# git commit and push even although no changes have been made, it's necessary to trigger web hook

Tags: git

I need to trigger commit and push although no changes have been made and the commit and push are not needed, but I do need it as each commit and push triggers a webhook.

So when I do:

```
git commit -am "release 1"
```

I'm getting:

```
On branch feature/X-111_Support
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/X-111_Support'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

As it was my previous commit. Also the files have not changed at all. How can I just commit and push it? This is done via script so no interactive mode allowed.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Why was the webhook not triggered when you *actually* pushed the commit? What would you expect git to do when you try to create a commit without any changes?

Comment: It's not possible,but you could add tag to the commit and use another webhook for tags, or you could change a fake file with a version number or a release note

Comment: its triggering webhook that trigger CI flow. this is the case which can't be changed 
(legacy )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git commit --allow-empty -am 'empty commit'`

Comment: winner! answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care the latest hash changing, you can do `git commit --amend --no-edit && git push --force`.

This will only change the `Commit` and `CommitDate` information of your latest commit, which will make the hash change so you will need to force push.

Comment: gives this msg :
You asked to amend the most recent commit, but doing so would make
it empty. You can repeat your command with --allow-empty, or you can
remove the commit entirely with "git reset HEAD^".